# PHP convert XML with mixed array children to JSON keeping the child order

Tags: php, json, xml, simplexml

I know how to use SimpleXML to convert XML to JSON, but when there're multiple kinds of children in the same node, how to keep the order information?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('
<root>
    <a id="0"></a>
    <b id="0"></b>
    <b id="1"></b>
    <a id="1"></a>
    <a id="2"></a>
</root>
');
echo json_encode($xml->children());
```

The code printed things below:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "@attributes": {
        "id": "0"
      }
    },
    {
      "@attributes": {
        "id": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "@attributes": {
        "id": "2"
      }
    }
  ],
  "b": [
    {
      "@attributes": {
        "id": "0"
      }
    },
    {
      "@attributes": {
        "id": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thus I won't know where the  elements are originally from, whether in the order `a, b, b, a, a` or `a, a, b, b, a`

So I wonder if there is a way to convert that XML into a JSON keeping this information? Maybe the result looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "tag": "a",
    "@attributes": {
      "id": "0"
    }
  },
  {
    "tag": "b",
    "@attributes": {
      "id": "0"
    }
  },
  {
    "tag": "b",
    "@attributes": {
      "id": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "tag": "a",
    "@attributes": {
      "id": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "tag": "a",
    "@attributes": {
      "id": "2"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<root>
    <a id="0"></a>
    <b id="0"></b>
    <b id="1"></b>
    <a id="1"></a>
    <a id="2"></a>
</root>
XML;

$xe = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$a = $xe->xpath('*');
$a = array_map(function ($e) {
  $item = (array) $e;
  $item['tag'] = $e->getName();
  return $item;
}, $a);
echo json_encode($a, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

*Output*

```
[
    {
        "@attributes": {
            "id": "0"
        },
        "tag": "a"
    },
    {
        "@attributes": {
            "id": "0"
        },
        "tag": "b"
    },
    {
        "@attributes": {
            "id": "1"
        },
        "tag": "b"
    },
    {
        "@attributes": {
            "id": "1"
        },
        "tag": "a"
    },
    {
        "@attributes": {
            "id": "2"
        },
        "tag": "a"
    }
]
```

Comment: Many thanks! But what if the XML has a namespace? xpath returns empty array then

Comment: @I2_wadxm, the asterisk seems to work even with namespaced XML. [Example](https://eval.in/693481). But it is possible use the DOM extension instead of SimpleXML. [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) allows to register namespace: `$xp->registerNamespace('myns', 'http://...');`, then use it in the XPath expressions: `/root/myns:*`.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over children and set `tag` to each element. Something like this:

```
$result = [];
foreach($xml->children() as $tag => $e) {
    $tagged = json_decode(json_encode($e));
    $tagged->tag = $tag;
    $result[] = $tagged;
}
echo json_encode($r);
```